What is the basis for the view of Oneness in Theravada?
What is the historical and scriptural basis for the modern Theravada Buddhist View "Life is one and indivisible", "everything is one"?
Is this a view that has been added later?
Is it a misrepresentation of right understanding?
This question was supred from the discussion with @ChrisW here

SN 12.48 lists 'oneness' ('ekatta') as one of four wrong non-Buddha world views:

At Savatthī. Then a brahmin who was a cosmologist approached the
Blessed One … and said to him:
“How is it, Master Gotama: does all exist?”
“‘All exists’: this, brahmin, is the oldest cosmology.”
“Then, Master Gotama, does all not exist?”
“‘All does not exist’: this, brahmin, is the second cosmology.”
“How is it, Master Gotama: is all a unity?”
“‘All is a unity (oneness; ekatta)’: this, brahmin, is the third cosmology (world-view; state-of-the-world; lokāyata; refer to discussion; refer to DD essay).”
“Then, Master Gotama, is all a plurality?”
“‘All is a plurality’: this, brahmin, is the fourth cosmology.
Without veering towards either of these extremes, the Tathagata teaches the Dhamma by the middle….”
When this was said, that brahmin said to the Blessed One:
“Magnificent, Master Gotama!… From today let Master Gotama remember me
as a lay follower who has gone for refuge for life.”
SN 12.48


Great sutta, I forgot about that one.

What is the basis for the view of Oneness in Theravada?
Oneness is a felt experience in meditation and jhanic practice of the mind converging onto its object. It is also a concept that has grown in various Buddhist schools outside of Theravada. Early suttas point to the world view of oneness as a wrong view, as it is outside of the middle path.
Oneness in the Suttas
Perception of Oneness in meditation


[DN 1: 3.22] "abides in the second jhāna, with inner tranquillity and oneness of mind"

[AN 6.42]  “I see, Nāgita, a forest-dwelling bhikkhu sitting and dozing in the  forest. It then occurs to me: ‘Now this venerable one will dispel this sleepiness and fatigue and attend only to the perception of forest, [a state of] oneness.’ For this reason I am pleased with this bhikkhu’s dwelling in the forest.

[AN 6.42 (see note)] Bhikkhu Bodhi's notes: “Oneness: he will bring to mind just the perception of the forest, a one-pointed state of uniformity”


Teachings of the Buddha copyright wisdom publications

As a Wrong View

The wrong view of oneness as mentioned in this post --> Alternative translation [SN 12.48]

Modern Historical Influences
Buddhist Romanticism
Ajahn Ṭhānissaro writes a work that covers this topic:

"In fact, as we will see when we examine the logical implications of the Romantic worldview… in a universe where all are part of a larger Oneness, no one has freedom of choice even in common, everyday matters. People simply have to follow their nature, with no choice as to what that nature might be. But as the Buddha pointed out, if there were no freedom of choice, the idea of a path of practice would make no sense, because no one would be free to choose whether or not to practice it."
Copyright 2015, Buddhist Romanticism, Thānissaro Bhikkhu

Christmas Humphries
Christmas Humphries in his classic influential book Buddhism 1951:

"All things are One and have no life apart from it ; the One is all things and incomplete without the least of them"
“for he who realises the full oneness of this life”
“Perfection is then the sense of oneness with all that is”
(In relation to Buddhism)… “It is mysticism in the sense that it strives for intuitive realization of the oneness of the universe…
“…based on a reverence for its source and the oneness which such a source entails”

Theosophical Society
The founders of the Theosophical Society, Helena Petrovna Blavatsky and Colonel Henry Steel Olcott, publicly declared themselves Buddhists in 1880. The Theosophical Society was a great influence in time when Buddhistic and spiritual interest was growing (in the west as alternative to Christianity).
Some of the organisations key ideas clearly promote the view of oneness.

"These are some of the ideas that have been circulating around The Theosophical Society since 1875:

There is one fundamental law and that is unity; at a deep level all is One
There is no dead matter; everything in Nature is a product of consciousness
The universe is eternal; the periodic playground of numberless worlds and of life
There is a fundamental identity of all souls with the universal Over-Soul
Each individual being goes through a process of spiritual evolution according to cyclic and karmic laws
Everything that happens is the result of natural law"

Theosophy: Revisiting the Ancient Wisdom

Ananda Metteyya/Charles Henry Allan Bennett
Founder of the first Theravada Buddhist Society in England (that later became the London Buddhist Society), the first main Theravada Bhikkhu Buddhist Missionary and advocate. He was a previous member of the Theosophical society before becoming a monk. The Venerable at that time speaks of oneness of meditation/jhana, oneness of Dhamma, but like Humpheres also oneness more aligned undefined views seems to be sometimes entangled in his teachings. His works were put into public libraries reading rooms around the world as a part of the mission in the early 1900's.


“We have seen how the Right View of Life, teaching as it does Life's Oneness, makes for Compassion, for endurance, for the ennobling of all our relations with life. No more, as in the View of Self-hood, looking on self and life as two different things, we have understood them One. … by making this understanding of our oneness with it enter, in practice, into all our daily ways as pity and as love.”
“by purifying heart and life, learning the great lesson of its Oneness and our part in it, surely must we presently find Peace, find Sorrow's End…”
“This Sila, simple though it may sound in words, and well though we all know the nature of its injunctions, is the essential preliminary ; there is no Samadhi, no mental Oneness, to be obtained without it.”
“And this Samadhi this steady burning of the flame of life and all the practices that lead thereto, are designed to the sheltering, even though it be but momentary, of the flickering flame ; it is only in its steady-burning ardor that the higher wisdom, the true understanding of the Oneness of Life that makes for Peace, can be won.”
“To realise the Oneness of life, and live accordingly that is the aim of every practice of the Buddhist Culture of the Mind.”
“meaning the Understanding that there is no self in truth, for Life is One, and One alone ; the Understanding that this One Life is pervaded in all its parts by the three characteristic signs Impermanency, Subjection to Suffering, and Absence of real Self-hood…”
“ … learning the great lesson of its Oneness and our part in it”
“All Life is One, as are all the ocean's waters…”

The religion of Burma and other papers by Ānanda Mettēyya

Sir Edwin Arnold
The Light of Asia by Sir Edwin Arnold was an early work in 1879, which also had an influence on early Buddhism in the west as well as Charles Henry Allan Bennett.

"Unto NIRVANA!  He is one with life"
Light of Asia, By Sir Edwin Arnold

Other Buddhist schools influence on the view of oneness
There seem to be references to Buddhist thought focused on oneness.

Traditions which view the world as ultimately all a manifestation of one underlying 'divine essence' (for example) might thus regard experiences of 'oneness with the divine essence of the universe' as the whole point of practice.
Becoming one with everything... and going beyond (Cheltenham Zen)


"One’s life and the environment are often viewed as being completely distinct, but from the comprehensive viewpoint of Buddhist philosophy, they are one and inseparable."
The Oneness of Life and Its Environment (Soka Gakkai)

Thich Nhat Hanh

We are here to awaken from the illusion of separateness
(How to Connect)

Holiness the 14th Dalai Lama

"In the past there was too much emphasis on my continent, my nation, my religion. Now that thinking is out of date. Now we really need a sense of oneness of seven billion human beings."
Dalai Lama: Seven billion people 'need a sense of oneness'


"We must continually consider the oneness of humanity, remembering that we all want to be happy. And indeed, everyone has a right to a happy life. Along the way we may be faced with problems, but we must not lose hope. We must keep up our determination without being impatient to achieve quick results."
Press Release: Dalai Lama, The Art of Hope

Essence of Dzogchen
Maybe more inline with the early view of an arahant overcoming good and evil and the attaining the Dhamma element:

"If my practice is to be the servant of all beings, it means all the experiences of bliss and suffering are of one taste, and experiencing the non separation of good and bad is my practice."
"At this stage we also speak of one taste. This means that even the subtle dualistic concept(s)… must be abandoned.
We must be without any conflict or effort to practice; we must go beyond the concept of practice and practitioner. These concepts are freed in the primordial state and we remain in pure mind without meditation and without distraction. In fact, in Dzogchen the best meditation is "non meditation," beyond meditation.

How ever the views seem to be separate from the attainment of an arahant, as they are working with defilement in samsara.

Finally, at the third stage, the passion should actually awaken presence and help us to remain in presence, making the presence more stable and profound. We are human beings and should have the five passions, which are the expressions of the energy of our natural karmic condition. If we are able to understand their nature, then they become an ornament of our practice. This identity of presence and
passion is the principle known as "one taste."
(Wonders Of The Natural Mind: The Essence of Dzogchen in the Native Bon Tradition of Tibet - by Tenzin Wangyal)

Lotus Sūtra
One of the most influential Buddhist Mahāyāna sūtras. While Theravada story of Lord Buddha ends with His Parinibbāna, the Lotus Sūtra goes on to add an additional final teaching of Shakyamuni Buddha, and outlying the Bodhisattva path for all beings, and a clear shift in fundamental teachings.

"The White Lotus of the Good Dharma, popularly known as the Lotus Sūtra, is taught by Buddha Śākyamuni on Vulture Peak to an audience that includes bodhisattvas from countless realms, as well as bodhisattvas who emerge from under the ground, from the space below this world. Buddha Prabhūtaratna, who has long since passed into nirvāṇa, appears within a floating stūpa to hear the sūtra, and Śākyamuni enters the stūpa and sits beside him... (this)... the notion that the Buddha’s life, enlightenment, and parinirvāṇa were simply manifestations of his transcendent buddhahood, while he continues to teach eternally."
The White Lotus of the Good Dharma

Miao-lo and the ten principles of oneness
The main proponent found maybe Zhanran Jingxi Zhanran, sometimes called Miao-lo who was the sixth patriarch of the Tiantai school of Chinese Buddhism. The Ten principles of oneness are set forth by Miao-lo (711–782 AD) in The Annotations on “The Profound Meaning of the Lotus Sutra.”


The oneness of body and mind. What one observes in meditation is one mind or one thought, which is an indivisible whole of body and mind.
The oneness of the internal and the external. Though the object of meditation is divided into two—the internal object, or the realm of one mind, a psychosomatic entity; and the external object, or the external world of physical and spiritual phenomena—these two are non-dual because one mind embodies the three truths and includes all three thousand realms.
The oneness of the result of practice and the true nature of life. This means that the true nature of life, or the true aspect of all phenomena, is no different from what one ultimately attains through Buddhist practice. The true nature moves one to practice, and practice enables one to manifest the true nature.
The oneness of cause and effect. “Cause” here means ordinary people, and “effect,” Buddhahood. The oneness of cause and effect means that the Buddha nature inherent in the ordinary person is the same as the Buddha nature that the Buddha has manifested.
The oneness of the impure and the pure. Because ignorance or delusion and enlightenment are two expressions of the same mind and essentially one, the impure mind shrouded in ignorance is itself the pure mind that is enlightened.
The oneness of life and its environment. Both the Buddha as a living being and the Buddha land as the environment exist in one mind and are therefore non-dual.
The oneness of self and others. “Self” means the Buddha, who teaches, and “others” means ordinary people, who are taught and enlightened. But they are non-dual because both the Buddha and ordinary people embody the three truths and are endowed with all three thousand realms. In other words, both self (Buddhahood) and others (the nine worlds) are inherent in one mind.
The oneness of thought, word, and deed. The Buddha saves people through his three categories of action—thought, speech, and behavior. These three categories of the Buddha are no different from those of ordinary people because they arise from the three thousand realms inherent in both. Moreover, these three exist in one mind as a psychosomatic whole and therefore are one.
The oneness of the provisional and true teachings. The Buddha preaches the provisional teachings (the three vehicles) and the true teaching (the one vehicle) according to the people’s capacity. Because they both spring from the Buddha’s enlightened mind, however, they are non-dual.
The oneness of benefits. Though people receive different benefits according to the level of the Buddha’s teaching that they practice (such as provisional and true), both the Buddha and the people ultimately enjoy the same benefit, just as plants in a field are all nourished equally by the rain.

The Ten onenesses (Soka Gakkai)

Summary
In summary while the early Theravada Buddhist view of oneness may be connected to samadhi experiences, or even the taste of Dhamma, later teachings expressing oneness don't seem to provide any  foundations in the Theravada school (the lineage of the elders) for such views.

"Everything is One"  and "Everything is Many"

Both these views seem to be extremes and the Tathagata teaches the Dhamma that is in the middle to void such extremes.

Perhaps, the oneness alluded by religious leaders like Thich Nhat Hanh and Dalai Lama refers to the interconnectness of all living things. Such as to destroy the forests is to destroy ourselves and the previous generation burning fossil fuels causes climate warming for later generations. It might be misleading to say we are one due to this interconnectness. Likewise to deny this connection will potentially create more harm to everyone.

@Desmon Isn't it an identity-view? "I am (this or that)", e.g. "I am the forest" etc. IMO you can see a connection between "cutting trees" and "climate change" -- without "everything is one in essence", or "I am you and you are me" etc.

@ChrisW Agreed that "Everything is One" and "Everything is Many" get in the way of recognizing the inter-dependency of living things. I feel seeing interconnectedness might instead be the middle way. This is not just about another view/perception but survival. Buddhism is about reality and not seeing things as they really are will eventually affect our ability to survive on earth.

Hinduism (...religions) also encourages the belief that the universe is interconnected, the concept of non-duality, or that all things are one. The idea of divine connectedness and the light of ātman is also emphasized.  I wonder the bases for using these terms in Dhamma? I feel these are commonly used, but can be easily taken out of context and possibly lead to wrong view?

I think the suttas more speak of our suffering and path to that end. Of the Dhamma and the power of that inner Light to travel to the far shore. I don't know the interconnectedness is emphasised, but rather that each being must take up the challenge of their own spiritual warfare. I suppose a Buddha's compassion is immeasurable, so that would touch on cosmic awe, but they are rare beings and the difficult path. No Buddhistic religions would exist if it wasn't for this rare Buddha Gautama. Harmony in the Sangha I guess is another form of interconnected that has not been mentioned.

+1 for easily taken out of context and possibly lead to wrong view. The opposite of unity or oneness is self-centredness or selfishness which is equally problematic. Perhaps I'll put up a question on this, thanks.
